# Why does Json(obj) convert apostrophe to \u0027?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am working with ASP.NET MVC 5 and there is an action method that returns a JsonResult.

```
// Sample code
public JsonResult GetBookByISBN(int isbn)
{
  return Json(new { book = "It's a Battlefield" })
}
```

However, the Json returned is

```
{"book":"It\u0027s a Battlefield"}
```

After some research, I do understand that `\u0027` is an apostrophe in Unicode, however, I do not get why it has to be converted to a Unicode as I have seen Json strings that uses ' within a value. I have tried escaping it by adding \ before ' but it did nothing.

To sum up my question, is this a normal behavior for serializing an object to Json? What is the reason for it and is there a way to fix it? I don't want to make deserializing it complicated if it does.

I would appreciate it if anyone could help me understand what is going on.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21498090/convert-json-unicode-to-utf8.

Comment: The thing I want to know isn't how to decode it. I want to know why it gets converted to Unicode and if that's normal or not as I don't want to make deserializing it complicated.

Comment: It annoys me too, but it works (and is normal), so just learn to live with it. There's no real reason to do it, which is why I find it annoying too

Comment: This seems to be related to [the default behavior of System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-character-encoding), but I'm not as well-versed in how to get around it in this scenario. The reason that link gives is because the apostrophe is a special character in HTML... though I think that's pretty over-zealous.

Comment: Thanks for the comments everyone. I have read that documentation when I was researching this behavior but I was not sure if ' is a non-ASCII character

Answer (score -2):

You are using  System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer . You can live as it is since it doesn't affect the result, but I recommend to use a Newtonsoft.Json

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;

 builder.Services.AddControllers()
.AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
  options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver =
        new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver());
```